# How can I add a css class to a single cell at runtime in material-react-table?

Tags: tanstack, material-react-table

I have a table instance and get a reference to the row and cell I need to update, however there seems to be no easy way to add a css class to the cell at runtime. What am I missing here?

```
if (tableInstanceRef.current) {
 const theRow = tableInstanceRef.current.getRow(changedKey);
 const theCells = theRow.getAllCells();
 const cell = theCells.at(4); //how to add a css class to this cell?
 console.log(cell);
}
```